# How to set root URL for Goutte driver?

Tags: symfony, routes, behat, goutte

I've started learning to use Behat and I've hit a snag: from what I understand the Goutte driver is simulating a user interaction that will follow pre-written scenarios, but when I launch Hehat through the console, i see that the url Goutte is reaching using `visit('/')` is http://localhost/ which is the WAMP homepage.

(I tried using visit() with the full url to no avail).

What I need is for Goutte to be by default at localhost:8000 which is where the test website is. So how can I specify which url is the root so that `visit('/')` will point to the homepage ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out that just adding a base url variable to behat.yml was enough to do it, my bad. Although it was found in no documentation, just the luck of finding the right thread.